# Running Python 3.2 and 2.7 on the Same Machine

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Is there an easy way to run both Python 2.7 and 3.2 on an OS X machine? I have been using IDLE with Python 3.2 and have numerous programs written using Python 3, so I don't really want to uninstall 3. However, I'm working on an assignment that uses 2.7 for a lot of its base code, so I'd like to be able to run 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X 10.7 and 10.8 come with Python 2.7 pre-installed; `/usr/bin/python`:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Installing additional versions of python isn't prohibited however; the [Python for Mac 2.7.3](http://www.python.org/getit/) installer won't interfere with the system install *or* your Python 3 installation.

Comment: So how would I use that pre-installed library on an interpreter like IDLE if I am currently running Python 3 on it?

Comment: You need to install a copy of IDLE for 2.7; see http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/

Comment: @user1427661: What happens when you type `python` into the shell? What version does it say it is? If you haven't changed any of the links, then chances are it will be the Apple distro of python 2.7.

Comment: Okay, but will installing IDLE for 2.7 override any of the files necessary to run IDLE for 3.x?

Comment: @user1427661: I believe they will remain separate.

Comment: Only one can be called `idle` if you're just running off the $PATH. But you'll have `idle3.2` and `idle2.7`, or you can explicitly run `/usr/bin/idle` (for the system version) and `/usr/local/bin/idle` or `/opt/local/bin/idle` or whatever (for the python.org, Homebrew, MacPorts, etc. version).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As the linked page says, you only need to install a custom IDLE for 2.7 if you're on OS X 10.6 and earlier. (Or if you've installed a custom 2.7 that didn't come with IDLE, of course.)